# Expo RN App: "An Error Occured! Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions."

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux, expo, redux-thunk

In the app, when I sign up, it does nothing. But when I log in, there is an error from the use effect call. "An Error Occured! Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions."  I'm using Thunk & redux. So, please help me out.
The code is here: https://github.com/nifty-coder/medical-records-trackr-app/

App error pics:

1. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1eHWJZoQ_dl40Pzdd5Ps0MGFG_03ls9Y7/view?usp=sharing/
2. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1AyRXeazGiai2EwZQH5ILFVf9P1hw6K27/view?usp=sharing/
3. https://docs.google.com/document/d/14JKY8dgRfjGf-652B1PsF3F8RjLj2EH9MRmzL59rNF4/view?usp=sharing/

Thank you,

Surya